# Apache httpd and Easy Apache 4 (Installing mod_wsgi for python app)

Tags: python-3.x, django, apache, mod-wsgi, easyapache-4

It's been a while but I am running into an issue and could not find any answers elsewhere.

I pay for a dedicated server that is running Easy Apache 4 with Centos 7. I have root access to everything so no limitations.

I am in the process of deploying a Python/Django app on the server for a client. When trying to install mod_wsgi it errors out stating it needs the package httpd-mmn. I can install the httpd module using yum but I am worried about conflicts since the server is using Easy Apache 4.

Is this a relevant concern? I have a bunch of php sites on my server and I am afraid I'll break it.

For the record, I do not want to use the experimental easy apache mod wsgi as it's, well...experimental and a use at your own risk situation.

Any thoughts or recommendations would be great.

Comment: Hi did you find any solution for this. I am stuck at exact same issue

Answer (score 1):

mod_wsgi is often built for a specific version of apache.
You are getting errors because your apache was installed by easyapache4.

I suggest you go with the experimental version for 2 reasons

1. You really don't have much of an option, unless you want to build everything yourself from ground up.
2. the ea-apache24-mod_wsgi has been available for install for at least 6 years now and I have searched thru the web and none has complained of errors or breaking things

If you (or anyone else) choose to go the experimental route, the process is

```
yum install ea4-experimental
yum install ea-apache24-mod_wsgi
```

Then modify the virtual host configs by creating directives and including these files

/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/std/2_4/{user}/{domain}/{includename}.conf

/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/std/2_4/{user}/{domain}/{includename}.conf (for SSL)

When done run this 3 commands to update the configs

```
/scripts/verify_vhost_includes
```

`/scripts/ensure_vhost_includes --user={user}`

`/scripts/rebuildhttpdconf`

Make sure to backup your httpd config before this step above

Finally restart your httpd and you should be good